# What can i use instead of Debug.Ray for drawing a lot of lines in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to create a semi realistic solar system and i want to be able to see the planets estimated movement in editor, i am currently using **Debug.Ray** for that and i also tried **Handle.DrawLine** for lack of better options but they are heavy on my computer very fast.

Is there any other way to draw lines in editor mode that is more suited for this kind of use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Gizmos.DrawLine you can find the documentation for it here at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawLine.html

Comment: Not as fast as i would have like but a lot better thank you.